# Auto fix common typo in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin, editor

Lets say for example I write many times priavte instead private.

Is there a way to let Eclipse automatically fix my common typo?

Something like construct a map of my common typo to its desire fix,
and then just let Eclipse fix it without asking me about that.

Are there any other IDE\editors that have such support?

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin support for automatically changing strings. The closest to your request are the templates of the Java editor, but even those must explicitly be activated using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.

To get around your problem, I suggest simply not to write that much yourself. If you want to declare a private field, type just "pr" and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to invoke code completion. Eclipse can do code completion quite well, often even without any trigger characters (try it with an empty class file).